# Use of Identity Management - KeyRock

Tags: fiware

I have follow the [installation guide](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Identity_Management_-_KeyRock_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide) without problems , but now I do not know what to do?

I have the http://localhost:8000/ runnig the fiware Lab form and I can with the idp user.

Now I want to use the rest ful api to create user or list user of my app:
GET /v2/Users/
but I don not how to do that? I only obtain errors. What is the next step?

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Try to edit your question, it is not readable like it is. For example, you can what with the idp user? And of course: never say "I obtain errors", if you want help, be more specific, otherwise nobody is able to help you.

Comment: Yes, please, provide us more details.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to list and create user.
You have to use JSON for that, you can get some general KeyStone examples here:
http://docs.openstack.org/developer/keystone/api_curl_examples.html